# Wandern aus oder auswandern - Auslasse des Prefixes

Tags: meaning, preposition, verb, sentence-structure, prefix

Kann man so sagen:

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten.

Oder soll man unbedingt auswandern benutzen

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten aus.

Mir scheint, dass der Prefix `aus` ausfallen kann, weil der Sinn schon in der Präposition `aus` inbegriffen wird.

> Ich bin aus dem Zug gestiegen.

kann man, glaube ich, als anderes Beispiel, statt

> Ich bin aus dem Zug ausgestiegen.

sagen, und der zweite Satz scheint mir "weniger korrekt" zu sein als der erste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da *wandern* und *auswandern* zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen haben (gehen vs. seinen Wohnsitz dauerhaft in ein anderes Land verlegen), führt das Weglassen der Silbe *aus-* auch zu einer andern Bedeutung.

Im ersten Beispiel ist das *aus* eben nicht Teil des trennbaren Verbs, sondern gehört zur Ortsangabe. Es kann nicht gleichzeitig zwei Elemente im Satz sein.

Also bedeutet

> Er wanderte aus Europa.

dass er im Zuge eines längeren Marsches Europa verließ, wohingegen

> Er wanderte aus Europa aus.

dass er nicht mehr in Europa lebt oder wohnt.
Praktisch gesehen ist es eher unwahrscheinlich, dass er diesen Vorgang zu Fuß vollzog.

Dass im zweiten Beispiel beide Formen korrekt sind, liegt nicht am *aus*, sondern daran, dass sowohl *steigen* als auch *aussteigen* für den konkreten Vorgang einen Zug zu verlassen benutzt werden können, der Bedeutungsunterschied ist minimal.

Answer (score 1):

auswandern (to emigrate) is a separable verb and has a different meaning than wandern (to hike). With separable verbs, if they are split, the 2nd part goes always last in the sentence. As such the two sentences of your first example use different verbs: wandern vs. auswandern:

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten

--> He hiked from Europe to the US. That's a pretty impressive deed in extremely cold winter via Siberia, I guess - but not what you want to express.

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten aus

--> He emigrated from Europe to the US.

In your latter example the verbs are also different, 'steigen' and 'aussteigen'. Yet the meaning of those two sentences is fairly similar if not identical:

> Ich bin aus dem Zug gestiegen

--> The verb used here is 'aus etwas steigen'. This means to step out of or climb out of something. This something can be also a box, a cave, etc. It's more general than the verb 'aus etwas aussteigen' which (in this meaning) means to exit or leave a vehicle (it can also be used more metaphorically, thus you can use it to indicate you quit attending or participating in an endeavour you comitted to, e.g. often used in the context of a criminal leaving the mafia, terrorist group or similar).

Comment: Warum eine Antwort auf Englisch, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch formuliert war?

Comment: Ich hätte dieser Antwort fast +1 gegeben, aber da die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde, die Antwort aber in einer Fremdsprache verfasst wurde, mache ich das nicht.

Comment: Weil... zuviel Englisch gelesen.

Answer (score 1):

### wandern

Das Verb »wandern« beschreibt eine sportliche Art der Fortbewegung, ähnlich wie »laufen« oder »schwimmen«. Beim Wandern zeiht man festes Schuhwerk an, packt einen Rucksack und geht dann eine weite Strecke, wobei man meist größere Siedlungsgebiete meidet. Das, was beim Wandern wesentlich ist, ist, dass man eine lange Strecke zu Fuß geht.

Der Satz

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten.

Bedeutet, dass sich jemand in Europe Wanderschuhe anzieht, Proviant in einem Rucksack mitnimmt und dann zu Fuß in die USA geht, wobei - wegen der nicht vorhandenen Landverbindung - ein Teil des Weges auf einem Schiff zurückgelegt werden muss.

### auswandern

Das Verb »auswandern« bedeutet, dass jemand seine Heimat für immer verlässt um den Rest seines Lebens an einem anderen Ort zu verbringen. Das Wort sagt nichts darüber aus, auf welche Weise man sich vom Ursprungsort zum Zielort bewegt. In den meisten Fällen wird man das an Bord eines Fahrzeuges sein, das ist aber nicht wesentlich. Wesentlich ist, dass man beim Auswandern seinen Wohnsitz in ein anderes Land verlagert.

Der Satz

> Er wanderte aus Europa in die Vereinigten Staaten aus.

bedeutet, dass jemand seinen bisherigen Wohnsitz in Europa aufgibt um zukünftig in den USA zu leben.

---

### Trennbare Verben

Das Verb *»auswandern«* ist ein trennbares Verb. Wenn man einen Satz im Futur I bildet, steht jedes Vollverb in seiner Nennform am Ende des Satzes, egal ob es trennbar ist oder nicht:

> Alex wird über die Alpen wandern.
> Erika wird das Rheintal durchwandern.
> Heinz wird aus Europa auswandern.

Dasselbe gilt, wenn man einen Satz im Präsens formuliert und dabei ein Modalverb verwendet:

> Alex darf über die Alpen wandern.
> Erika möchte das Rheintal durchwandern.
> Heinz will aus Europa auswandern.

In den genannten Beispielen hat das Hilfverb bzw. das Modalverb die Rolle des finiten Verbs übernommen, also jenes Verbs, das so gebeugt wird, dass es mit dem Subjekt in Zahl (singular oder plural) und Person (1., 2. oder 3. Person) übereinstimmt. Das finite Verb ist auch jedes Verb, dass in deutschen Aussagesätzen immer an Position 2 steht. Alle anderen Verben, die im selben Satz zusätzlich noch vorkommen, sind infinite Verben (Verben in der Nennform) und sie stehen am Ende des Satzes.

Will man nun einen Satz im Präsens bilden, der kein Modalverb verwendet, dann muss eines der Verben, die zuvor am Ende standen, die Rolle des finiten Verbs einnehmen, als sich in Zahl und Person an das Subjekt anpassen und auf Position 2 vorrücken.

Bei untrennbaren Verben (egal ob mit oder ohne Vorsilbe) vollzieht das ganze Wort diesen Wechsel:

> Alex wandert über die Alpen.
> Erika durchwandert das Rheintal.

Bei trennbaren Verben bewegt sich aber nur der Hauptteil des Verbs nach vor, die Vorsilbe bleibt am Ende des Satzes stehen:

> Heinz wandert aus<sub>1</sub> Europa aus<sub>2</sub>.

Dabei ist das mit 1 gekennzeichnete Wort *»aus«* die Präposition des Präpositionalobjekts *»aus Europa«,* das den Ort bezeichnet, den Heinz nun verlässt. Das mit 2 gekennzeichnete Wort *»aus«* ist **keine** Präposition, sondern es ist die abgetrennte Vorsilbe des trennbaren Verbs *»auswandern«*

Transformiert man diese Sätze in die Vergangenheit, kommt wieder ein Hilfsverbs in den Satz, das die Rolle des finiten Verbs übernimmt, was bedeutet, dass das Vollverb wieder am Ende des Satzes steht, diesmal aber aber als Partizip II:

> Alex ist über die Alpen gewandert.
> Erika hat das Rheintal durchwandert.
> Heinz ist aus Europa ausgewandert.

Hier fällt auf, dass beim nicht zusammengesetzten Verb das Präfix *»ge-« angefügt wird und das zusammengesetzte untrennbare Verb »durchwandern« nur seine Endung ändert (ern -> ert). Bei einem trennbaren Verb kommt auch die Silbe *»ge«* hinzu, aber nicht als Präfix, sondern als Interfix zwischen Vorsilbe und Hauptteil.

---

### aus etwas steigen

Wenn jemand aus einem Behälter steigt, dann muss man, um den Behälter zu verlassen, sich mit einem Bein nach dem anderen über ein Hindernis bewegen. Das Verb »steigen« bezeichnet nämlich eigentlich eine Bewegung nach oben. (Ein Kind lässt einen Drachen steigen. Ein Bergsteiger steigt auf einen Berg.) Allerdings kann man auch auf einer Leiter nach unten steigen, in diesem Fall steht also die kletternde Bewegung im Vordergrund.

Der Satz

> Ich bin aus dem Zug gestiegen.

Bedeutet, dass jemand beim Verlassen Zuges entweder ein Hindernis überwinden musste, oder auf etwas, das einer Leiter ähnelt, aus dem Zug geklettert ist.

### aus etwas aussteigen

Das Verb *»aussteigen«* bedeutet: Ein Fahrzeug verlassen. Im übertragenen Sinn kann *»aussteigen«* auch das Verlassen einer sozialen Gruppe bedeuten.

Der Satz

> Ich bin aus dem Zug ausgestiegen.

Bedeutet, dass ich den Zug verlassen habe.

Man kann beide Sätze auch in die Gegenwart transferieren:

> Ich steige aus dem Zug. (Klettern)
> Ich steige aus dem Zug aus. (gewöhnliches Verlassen)